# Trying to change parameters in JQuery plugin file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JQuery plugin i am using as part of my project. The file is located in the root of my solution folder under a file called "jquery.tablePagination.js" I want to alter some of the parameters inside of the file without hard coding the data.

The script is as follows..

```
(function ($) {

$.fn.tablePagination = function (settings) {
    var defaults = {
        firstArrow: (new Image()).src = "./images/first.gif",
        prevArrow: (new Image()).src = "./images/prev.gif",
        lastArrow: (new Image()).src = "./images/last.gif",
        nextArrow: (new Image()).src = "./images/next.gif",
        rowsPerPage: 5,
        currPage: 1,
        optionsForRows: [5, 10],
        ignoreRows: []
    };
    settings = $.extend(defaults, settings);

    return this.each(function () {
        var table = $(this)[0];
        var totalPagesId = '#' + table.id + '+#tablePagination #tablePagination_totalPages';
        var currPageId = '#' + table.id + '+#tablePagination #tablePagination_currPage';
        var rowsPerPageId = '#' + table.id + '+#tablePagination #tablePagination_rowsPerPage';
        var firstPageId = '#' + table.id + '+#tablePagination #tablePagination_firstPage';
        var prevPageId = '#' + table.id + '+#tablePagination #tablePagination_prevPage';
        var nextPageId = '#' + table.id + '+#tablePagination #tablePagination_nextPage';
        var lastPageId = '#' + table.id + '+#tablePagination #tablePagination_lastPage';

        var possibleTableRows = $.makeArray($('tbody tr', table));
        var tableRows = $.grep(possibleTableRows, function (value, index) {
            return ($.inArray(value, defaults.ignoreRows) == -1);
        }, false)

        var numRows = tableRows.length
        var totalPages = resetTotalPages();
        var currPageNumber = (defaults.currPage > totalPages) ? 1 : defaults.currPage;
        if ($.inArray(defaults.rowsPerPage, defaults.optionsForRows) == -1)
            defaults.optionsForRows.push(defaults.rowsPerPage);


        function hideOtherPages(pageNum) {
            if (pageNum == 0 || pageNum > totalPages)
                return;
            var startIndex = (pageNum - 1) * defaults.rowsPerPage;
            var endIndex = (startIndex + defaults.rowsPerPage - 1);
            $(tableRows).show();
            for (var i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
                if (i < startIndex || i > endIndex) {
                    $(tableRows[i]).hide()
                }
            }
        }

        function resetTotalPages() {
            var preTotalPages = Math.round(numRows / defaults.rowsPerPage);
            var totalPages = (preTotalPages * defaults.rowsPerPage < numRows) ? preTotalPages + 1 : preTotalPages;
            if ($(totalPagesId).length > 0)
                $(totalPagesId).html(totalPages);
            return totalPages;
        }

        function resetCurrentPage(currPageNum) {
            if (currPageNum < 1 || currPageNum > totalPages)
                return;
            currPageNumber = currPageNum;
            hideOtherPages(currPageNumber);
            $(currPageId).val(currPageNumber)
        }

        function resetPerPageValues() {
            var isRowsPerPageMatched = false;
            var optsPerPage = defaults.optionsForRows;
            optsPerPage.sort();
            var perPageDropdown = $(rowsPerPageId)[0];
            perPageDropdown.length = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < optsPerPage.length; i++) {
                if (optsPerPage[i] == defaults.rowsPerPage) {
                    perPageDropdown.options[i] = new Option(optsPerPage[i], optsPerPage[i], true, true);
                    isRowsPerPageMatched = true;
                }
                else {
                    perPageDropdown.options[i] = new Option(optsPerPage[i], optsPerPage[i]);
                }
            }
            if (!isRowsPerPageMatched) {
                defaults.optionsForRows == optsPerPage[0];
            }
        }

        function createPaginationElements() {
            var htmlBuffer = [];
            htmlBuffer.push("<div id='tablePagination'>");
            htmlBuffer.push("<span id='tablePagination_perPage'>");
            htmlBuffer.push("<select id='tablePagination_rowsPerPage'><option value='5'>5</option></select>");
            htmlBuffer.push("per page");
            htmlBuffer.push("</span>");
            htmlBuffer.push("<span id='tablePagination_paginater'>");
            htmlBuffer.push("<img id='tablePagination_firstPage' src='" + defaults.firstArrow + "'>");
            htmlBuffer.push("<img id='tablePagination_prevPage' src='" + defaults.prevArrow + "'>");
            htmlBuffer.push("Page");
            htmlBuffer.push("<input id='tablePagination_currPage' type='input' value='" + currPageNumber + "' size='1'>");
            htmlBuffer.push("of <span id='tablePagination_totalPages'>" + totalPages + "</span>");
            htmlBuffer.push("<img id='tablePagination_nextPage' src='" + defaults.nextArrow + "'>");
            htmlBuffer.push("<img id='tablePagination_lastPage' src='" + defaults.lastArrow + "'>");
            htmlBuffer.push("</span>");
            htmlBuffer.push("</div>");
            return htmlBuffer.join("").toString();
        }

        if ($(totalPagesId).length == 0) {
            $(this).after(createPaginationElements());
        }
        else {
            $('#tablePagination_currPage').val(currPageNumber);
        }
        resetPerPageValues();
        hideOtherPages(currPageNumber);

        $(firstPageId).bind('click', function (e) {
            resetCurrentPage(1)
        });

        $(prevPageId).bind('click', function (e) {
            resetCurrentPage(currPageNumber - 1)
        });

        $(nextPageId).bind('click', function (e) {
            resetCurrentPage(currPageNumber + 1)
        });

        $(lastPageId).bind('click', function (e) {
            resetCurrentPage(totalPages)
        });

        $(currPageId).bind('change', function (e) {
            resetCurrentPage(this.value)
        });

        $(rowsPerPageId).bind('change', function (e) {
            defaults.rowsPerPage = parseInt(this.value, 10);
            totalPages = resetTotalPages();
            resetCurrentPage(1)
        });

    })
};
})(jQuery);
```

I want to be able to alter the following settings: RowsPerPage and OptionforRows.

I have tried to copy and paste the code from the script directly into my .aspx file next to some other Jquery/JavaScript I already have however the plugin doesn't run when I do this.

Could it be possible to write to the settings part of the file from the code behind? It would also work if the file could read the settings from a certain hidden field but I can't get it to run on my .aspx to do this. I'm not sure how to go about solving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up solving this issue by first copying the script and pasting in my .aspx file. I was originally copying the code inside of the document ready function:

```
   $(document).ready(function)
```

Once I have had this done It was quite easy to pass through a variable from the code behind to be used as the required setting.

```
rowsPerPage: <%=PageRowAmount%>,
```

For the code behind I have added the following:

```
Public PageRowAmount As Integer = 10
```

and in the page_load I have added

```
Page.DataBind()
```

Solved!